# How to convert the extracted text from PDF to JSON or XML format in Python?

Tags: python, json, xml, pypdf

I am using PyPDF2 to extract the data from PDF file and then converting into Text format?

PDF format for the file is like this:

```
Name : John 
Address: 123street , USA 
Phone No:  123456
Gender: Male 

Name : Jim 
Address:  456street , USA 
Phone No:  456899
Gender: Male
```

In Python I am using this code:

```
import PyPDF2
pdf_file = open('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Sampletest.pdf', 'rb')
read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
number_of_pages = read_pdf.getNumPages()
page = read_pdf.getPage(0)
page_content = page.extractText()
page_content
```

This is the outcome which I get from page_content:

```
 'Name : John \n \nAddress: 123street , USA \n \nPhone No:  123456\n \nGender: Male \n \n \nName : Jim \n \nAddress:  456street , USA \n \nPhone No:  456899\n \nGender: Male \n \n \n'
```

How do I format it in a JSON or XML format so that I could use extracted data in SQL server database.

I tried using this approach as well

```
import json
data = json.dumps(page_content)
formatj = json.loads(data)
print (formatj)
```

Output:

```
Name : John 
Address: 123street , USA 
Phone No:  123456
Gender: Male 

Name : Jim 
Address:  456street , USA 
Phone No:  456899
Gender: Male
```

This is the same output which I have in my word file, but I don't think that this is in JSON format.

Comment: Where are you running this code? In the REPL? Have you tried `print(page_content)` instead? Having one variable on a line by itself doesn't produce any output in a script

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

Not so pretty, but this would get the job done, I think.  You would get a dictionary which then gets printed by the json parser in a nice, pretty format.

```
import json    

def get_data(page_content):
    _dict = {}
    page_content_list = page_content.splitlines()
    for line in page_content_list:
        if ':' not in line:
            continue
        key, value = line.split(':')
        _dict[key.strip()] = value.strip()
    return _dict

page_data = get_data(page_content)
json_data = json.dumps(page_data, indent=4)
print(json_data)
```

or, instead of those last 3 lines, just do this:

```
print(json.dumps(get_data(page_content), indent=4))
```

Comment: Thanks @UtahJarHead for the answer but it seems like I can only extract only one of the people information. In my case, I am getting this output.                                                           {
        "Name": "Jim",
        "Address": "456street , USA",
        "Phone No": "456899",
        "Gender": "Male"
}

Comment: Right.  The function I created, you are going to have to pick out each individual section.  For instance, each time you see `"Name:"`, you grab what's been gathered and shove it to the `get_data()` function, process it, and head over to get the next person's data.