# How to convert PDF document to JSON Using Python script

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, pypdf

Trying to convert an PDF form to JSON data using python

**Sample PDF Format :**

[image]

**Code :**

```
import PyPDF2
pdf_file = open('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\data.pdf', 'rb')
read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
number_of_pages = read_pdf.getNumPages()
page = read_pdf.getPage(0)
page_content = page.extractText()
import json
data = json.dumps(page_content)
formatj = json.loads(data)
```

But I am not getting the output the proper JSON Format

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52675556/how-to-convert-the-extracted-text-from-pdf-to-json-or-xml-format-in-python) link. If this is what you meant then this Q is a duplicate.

Comment: so what format are you getting?

Answer (score -2):

He will get a string by this.You need to convert `page_content` into `dictionary` first